# Changing css class from «fa fa-search» to «fa fa-refresh fa-spin» on a button, in angular http request?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome-4

I'm developing a Website with `ASP.NET`, `MVC5`, `HTML5` and `AngularJS`.

[image]

**Updated**

I have no warnings in Chrome console.

The font-awesome fonts are locally in my web project.

In my web.config have this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
```

I have a function that makes an Angular's `$http` request and I need to change the icon class when the button is pressed.

Currently, in my angular controller, I have this:

```
$scope.requested = false; // Initial value: false.

$scope.search = function (model) {
    $scope.requested = true; // When the function is called.

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: DFJB.systempath + "api/getdata",
        data: model
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.requested = false; // When the request is completed.
        console.log(data);  
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error: " + status);
    });
};
```

HTML5:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="frmModel.$invalid" type="submit">
    <i data-ng-class="{'fa fa-search': requested == false, 'fa fa-refresh fa-spin': requested == true}"></i>
    Search
</button>
```

However, it's not working properly.

**When the function is called the icon changes with an incorrect appearance:**
[image]

**When the request is completed the icon changes back with an incorrect appearance:**
[image]

What I wish visually:

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: create demo that replicates problem

Comment: It looks like the class `fa` is not being included in the resulting `class`. Have you tried removing `fa` from ng-class and moving it to `class`? It is needed regardless of `requested` status.

Comment: This `<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="requested = !requested">
    <i ng-class="{'fa fa-search': !requested, 'fa fa-refresh fa-spin': requested}"></i>
    Search
</button>` works fine for me and the right 'fa fa-refresh fa-spin' is displayed as expected.

Comment: @DianaR Yes, statically works well, the problem is when is programmatically with the mentioned function.

Comment: What about the requests to the server, are all of them posted and responded ok if you look in dev tools network tab?

Comment: @DianaR In the network tab everything is ok. I have no errors neither warnings, the fonts are successfully loaded with status 200 and type: font.

Comment: Ok. try to disable all the extensions in chrome and test again, it happens sometimes that extension are in conflict and causes weird issues.

Comment: @yvesmancera Yes, you're right. I removed the fa from ng-class and put class="fa". It's works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, you should try moving the necessary class `fa` to `class` since it's needed regardless of `requested` value.

Additionally, you can try the following syntax for ng-class:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="frmModel.$invalid" type="submit">
    <i class="fa" data-ng-class="requested? 'fa-refresh fa-spin': 'fa-search'"></i>
    Search
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should ensure that the `font-awesome`  loaded. see the `page source`.

and your form name should be `frmModel` like:

```
<form name="frmModel" data-ng-submit="search()">

      <input type="text" data-ng-model="userName" required>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="frmModel.$invalid">
           <i class="fa" data-ng-class="{'fa-search': !requested, 'fa-refresh fa-spin': requested}"></i>

           Search
      </button>
    </form>
```

[See PLUNKER WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXnA9tKJg22hBuXNSepv?p=preview)

Comment: Your demo looks well, but the problem still remains. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your font files from `font-awesome` library are not properly loaded into the browser. You should see the error in the browser's console.

If you are using the downloaded libraries, comment them and try to use directly from the cloud as given here http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

**Update**:

Also, can you please try to update your code like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="frmModel.$invalid" type="submit">
    <i class="fa" data-ng-class="{'fa-search': !requested, 'fa-refresh fa-spin': requested}"></i>
    Search
</button>
```

Adding `fa` class always to avoid adding and removing it again and again. Also, using `requested == false` to `!requested` and `requested == true` to `requested`.

Comment: I see no errors neither warnings on the console. I've updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is something like @yvesmancera's comment, one hour ago.